# Pentaho REST call to HTTPS?

Tags: https, pentaho

In Pentaho can I make a call to a rest service secured with HTTPS? I've tried the 'REST Client' step which has an input for truststore but I see no way to set the keystore.

Comment: To provide the target certificate, you can add it in a new keystore using keytool. Use this in the truststore

Comment: I tried adding my truststore certs to my keystore using keytool and specifying it and its password in the ssh tab and received "unable to find valid certification path to requested target".

Comment: I added my certificate to here using: keytool -import -alias example -keystore  C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.6.0_22\lib\security\cacerts -file example.cer. Do I add C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.6.0_22\lib\security\cacerts path in Rest Client Trust Store file?